# 3990x Aorus Pro wifi freeze on 20.04

Tags: 20.04, freeze, crash, amd-processor, gigabyte

I am experiencing random freezing on the following:

- GIGABYTE TRX40 AORUS PRO WIFI
- AMD Ryzen Threadripper 3990X 64CORE 128Threads
- CORSAIR VENGEANCE LPX 32GB x4 (128GB)
- CORSAIR Force Gen.4 PCIe MP600 2TB NVMe M.2 x 2 (4TB)
- NZXT Kraken X73 360mm Liquid Cooler
- Galax GT1030 EXOC 2G GDDR4
- COOLER MASTER V1300 PLATINUM FULL-MODULAR 80 PLUS POWER SUPPLY
- FRACTAL DESIGN DEFINE 7 ATX BLACK DARK

Ubuntu 20.04

We have tried different distros including fedora and pop_os and they have the same issue
System76 use this motherboard and processor so I though it would be ok.

We have updated the bios and tweaked settings with no luck.
Ran a full memtest and it showed no errors.

we returned it to the shop we got it from and they have been running tests on it.

They put the latest windows version and it did seem to be more stable but It crashed when running vmware with Ubuntu on it. I didn't run it long enough after wards to see if it crashed on its own.

We then switched back to Linux and started switching components. We switched the memory and then video card and we were still getting crashes. Then they switched out the processor for the 3960x. I ran builds all night long and it had no problems whatsoever.

The guys at the shop have said they will send the processor back to the vendor and they will replace but I'm still not convinced this is the issue.

Freezing happens at random it can happily do a few builds with make -j1000 and then crash when I open vim. I can't see anything obvious from the logs it looks to me like the whole system just halts.

Does anyone else have an idea of what my issue could be?

[logs on gdrive](http://drive.google.com/drive/folders/19lXsUqQwE5pUyOHYqHohAk5Ms1Ckgs8P?usp=sharing)

Comment: I fixed a similar issue with an AMD system by disabling "Automatic C-State Management" in BIOS. I would try that and see if it fixes the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out we did have a faulty processor. The shop sent it back to the vendor and got a replacement which has been running all weekend with no errors.

I would have swore it was a Linux software problem but looks like we just got unlucky with the hardware.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer, I just wanted to say that I am also experiencing freezes with my 3990x build, I also have 128GB (4x32GB) vengeance LPX and Gigabyte TRX40 motherboard (Designare). I have gotten freezes both when using 2080 TI and GTX 1080. I am using the latest nvidia driver (NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-450.57).

I had most frequent freezes trying to use ClearLinux but now I've probably had like 8 freezes with Ubuntu 20.04 as well. I updated the Kernel from 5.4 to 5.8 in the hope that it might help, which it didn't.

In my case the freeze is so bad I have to do a hard reset and the numlock on the keyboard is not even reacting

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the logs.

Each time the reboot starts immediately after "systemd-modules-load" is loading the module "lp", which is part of the `/etc/modules-load.d/cups-filters.conf`.